# How can I specify transformer Part number in BOM for manufacturing?

Tags: transformer, prototyping

I am new to the AC-DC converters design and I would like to know what is required to describe a transformer to the prototyping company so that they can either procure an existing one, or have enough details to construct one to properly meet my requirement.

What parameters are required to describe a transformer for a given task (or to procure an existing one that suits)?

Note: I was thinking that maybe there are some standard part numbers of transformers that could be used (something similar like resistors , capacitors ...) – but from the answers that I have received it seems that while "off the shelf" transformers exist, in many cases transformers are far less standardised than "simple" components.

---

Added:

I have so far received the following useful advice.
Is there anything else that I need to know?

- I need to talk to the prototyping company, to clarify what they can design and test,
- I probably need to provide a detailed drawing of core, winding area, margin tape placement, wire configuration, tape, termination, winding direction, tolerance, test instructions and how to mark it.
- If it's a bespoke design I need to design one to suit or to find a standard transformer that might do the job.
- I need to have a full understanding of what is required of the transformer to make it suitable for my application.

Comment: 'throwing stuff over the fence' rarely ends well in engineering. You need to talk to the prototyping company, to clarify what they can design and test, to decide what you need to design and test. Somebody is going to need to design, and to test, this transformer.

Comment: Probably with a detailed drawing on core, winding area, margin tape placement, wire configuration, tape, termination, winding direction, tolerance, test instructions and how to mark it.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. but my doubt is regarding the bill of material that I should provide to the manufacutring company. I was thinking that maybe there are some standard part numbers of transformers that could be used (something similar like resistors , capacitors ...)

Comment: @user3076262 more than likely and more than often it's a bespoke design so, you need to bite the bullet on this one or, find a standard transformer that might do the job. Given that you haven't revealed a design, there can be no real help finding a standard part but, if it's a flyback supply then premier magnetics do a lot of standard parts.

Comment: Sure, if you are using a COTS transformer. If you’re going into AC-DC design, you need to learn to design your own transformers.

Comment: @user3076262 Please check that my edit says what you want. The question was closed so I edited it to fit site requirements and reopened it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transformer is specified on a separate drawing, and you assign a customer (that is you!) part number to it yourself.

Transformers have way more parameters that would fit in a part number. They need an engineering drawing.

The manufacturer will also assign *their* part number to that same drawing. The title block on the drawing might then state:

Joe Consulting P/N T05032

Probodobodyne P/N XA-8874-102

“Joe Consulting” is a stand in for your business, “Probodobodyne” is a stand in for the manufacturer. Sometimes the words “Customer” and “Manufacturer” are used but that’s problematic when the same design may be made by several manufacturers, each assigning their own p/n.

Answer (score 4):

Transformers for custom power supplies are often custom wound, at least in my world. There are transformers for switching supplies that are available off the shelf from many manufacturers. As the designer, you need to find a suitable transformer and supply that part number since you know what specifications are important to your design and you have tested the suitability of said product with your topology.

If a custom transformer, create a separate drawing of the transformer that describes the winding geometries, wire type (solid, litz, bunched), wire diameters, wire insulation, tape placement, pinout, core, bobbin, clips, and any other pertinent information. The schematic BOM refers to that drawing number.

The transformer drawing will allow someone to custom wind the part. Other options: you can supply the assembly house with transformers you have wound and/or install the transformer yourself after you receive the assembled board.

Good idea to also have electrical information (inductance of the windings, leakage inductance, ...) so the transformer can be tested against the specifications.